# alias method or component using import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Why I can't do this

```
import { getData as get } from "axios";
```

so that I can use getData as an alias of get?

```
getData('url').then(resp)
```

else I have to do axios.get('url')

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: shouldn't that be `import { get as getData }`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and see the import statement

```js
import { get as getData  } from "axios";

class TestJs extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount(){
        getData('https://data.fixer.io/api/latest').then(function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               Hello World
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TestJs
```

Comment: @vol7ron - I won't directly run here. You must have REACTJS installed

Comment: Why is it a snippet again instead of a code block?  Also.. the snippet editor has ReactJS available, but your code still wouldn't run with it enabled.